# Run multiple sites from one IP in IIS7 on windows server 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7, and I'm using an ASP.NET app. I am trying to run multiple sites from one IP, but I can't access the sites from the outside. I can only access the Default website from outside but when I want to access the second one it does not work.
**host** configured for both sites: 
10.10.10.1      www.mydomain.com 
       and 
10.10.10.1      sport.mydomain.com

They both run fine locally on the Server and I have added a rule on the firewall to allow all inbound. but still
any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change the port for the second site.

Comment: i did assign: port 80 for site1 and port 8080 for site 2, but no chance

Comment: Is there any router involve in your network if yes then you need to open port 8080 on your router and also try to access site like (10.10.10.1:8080)

Comment: Thanks for your time.  No router on the net. Should I do some settings on DNS

Comment: can you post your site bindings?

Comment: What type of data are you interested in

Comment: Can you  explain more about your request